# Why can't I pass methods as objects?

Tags: c#, object, delegates

Let's say I have:

```
public void Print() { ... }
public void F(object o) { ... }
```

now I can do this:

```
Action a = t.Print;
F(a);
```

but not:

```
F(Print);
```

Why? why is it that I can pass in an `Action` as an `object`, but not a method? doesn't all delegates resolve to methods? shouldn't it be the same thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion to a delegate when castion as an `object`, because it cannot know **what type** of delegate to create. For example, `Print` matches both `Action` and `ThreadStart` - and about 40 other delegate types that match the `void SomeDelegateName()` signature (i.e. no parameters, no return value). Equally, without a delegate type, there is no way to resolve the *method group* (`Print` is a method group, not a method) to a single overload.

This works:

```
F((Action)Print);
```

Key point: there is absolutely nothing special about `Action` - it is just a delegate type - and it has the same signature as lots of other delegate types.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. "and it has the same signature as lots of other delegate types." - You mean user-created delegates right? - or other built-in ones?

Comment: @vexe both. I cited ThreadStart - that is built in. You can use reflection to find a lot of similar matches, but you'd need to load all the core assemblies to do a thorough job

Comment: @vexe see also: `System.Action`, `System.CrossAppDomainDelegate`, `System.Threading.ThreadStart`, `System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.CrossContextDelegate`, etc - all the same signature